# How to attach an animated object to a rig?

Tags: animation, armature, bones, workflow

[image: animated lamp]

I have an animated emergency light that should stick to the head of a little robot. Is this possible without rigging it? The robot is rigged with bones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's possible

1. Select the lamp
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+*Select* the armature
3. Enter into *Pose mode* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>)
4. Select the bone you want to attach the lamp to
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and select 'Bone relative'

[image]

Comment: Bone relative or just Bone should be fine yes, like noted in the other answer

Answer (score 1):

Parent it to one of the bones that are not deforming anything. Select the light, <kbd>Shift</kbd> *select* a bone in pose mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> = Bone.

Comment: Thank you guys! You are amazing!